# $A^\circ$ need not be connected even if $A$ is connected. (in $\mathbb{R}$)

Tags: general-topology

> $A^\circ$ need not be connected even if $A$ is connected. (in $\mathbb{R}$)

I realize that a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is connected iff it is an interval. This to me means that interior points are connected, even if they are singletons, because they are all limit points essentially.(?)

However, I have been reading some conflicting information stating that this may not always be the case. Can anyone enlighten me? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In $\mathbb{R}$, the interior of a connected set is connected. As you remarked, this is because the only connected sets in $\mathbb{R}$ are intervals, and the interior of an interval is an interval (or empty).

In $\mathbb{R}^2$, this is not true. Consider, for example, two tangent disks. This is a connected set, while the interior has a disconnection because of a single point missing where the circles were tangent.

Comment: Is this still the case for a singleton though? Because then there is only one element in interior, and there is nothing really connecting it. Though on the other hand I realize isolated points are different than singletons. So I presume isolated is open and connected but not sure of singleton.. thank you

Comment: If you have a singleton, its interior is *empty*, which is connected.

Comment: Right because by definition not separated. Thank you!!

Comment: You're very welcome.